# Rancher desktop, docker file shell commands are not working on mac m1 chip

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh, rancher, rancher-desktop

hi following are my docker file commands

```
ARG debianVersion=10.2
FROM debian:${debianVersion}
ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
ARG AGENT_WORKDIR=/home/${user}/agent
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${group}
RUN useradd -c "Jenkins user" -d /home/${user} -u ${uid} -g ${gid} -m ${user}
```

I am using rancher desktop on mac m1 chip.

On executing following command I a getting error

```
docker build -t test --platform linux/x86_64 .
```

Error message is as follows

```
[Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
---> Running in 7778b2303192
-c: 0: Can't open apt-get update
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Found that none of the shell commands are working getting error a non-zero code: 127 how to fix this?

Using rancher version **1.5.0**
Using container runtime **dockerd(moby)**
Using Kubernetes version **v1.21.14**

Comment: What is the base image (the image's `FROM` line)?  Are you certain you have an official copy of it; does something like `docker pull ubuntu:20.04` to re-download it from Docker Hub make any difference?

Comment: hi updated question using FROM debian:${debianVersion}

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to Rancher Desktop 1.4.1.

This works but if downgrading is not an option there are workarounds on the [Rancher Desktop Issues](https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues) site for [similar problems](https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/2685) like this:
[qemu workaround](https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-)

> As a temporary workaround, as root in the VM:
>
> ```
> Create /etc/conf.d/qemu-binfmt, with contents binfmt_flags="POCF"
> Run rc-update --update
> Run rc-service qemu-binfmt restart
> ```

Easy way to connect to the VM and run those commands is ([source](https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/5e1a0c7bcca4c735e716abf62afad389)):

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile:

```
…
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 debian:${debianVersion}
…
```

Build command:

```
docker build -t test --platform linux/arm64 .
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it `dockerd` runtime can only emulate other platform types (in the above case `--platform=linux/amd64`) on the `m1 chip` macs using `Docker Desktop`.

Try using the built in `nerdctl` that comes packaged with `Rancher Desktop`:

```bash
nerdctl build -t test --platform linux/amd64 .
nerdctl build -t test --platform linux/x86_64 .
```

N.B. I have found that even with emulation, some `--platform linux/x86_64` (linux/amd64) images still cannot be built, recently experienced that with official `selenium` set, but had no problem with `wso2` & `mailcatcher` images

Comment: tried this not working got same error

Comment: Unfortunately, it just maybe the container, some just cannot work with emulation. As a test, see how you fair with these under emulation: ```docker run --platform linux/x86_64 centos:8``` & ```docker run --platform linux/x86_64 ruby:alpine```

Comment: I have just built your image with Docker Desktop and got the container running. I am on Monterey 12.2.1. Wonder if Rancher Desktop is the issue ?  Both docker build and run commands used --platform linux/x86_64.